# Upgrading APC extension in MAMP

Tags: macos, php, macports, mamp, php-apc

I'm trying to upgrade the APC extension in MAMP. I have got installed MacPorts and with the following command I've installed the `autoconf`:

`sudo port install autoconf`

Then I've executed this command:

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/pecl upgrade apc`

and this is what appears on console:

```
downloading APC-3.1.13.tgz ...
Starting to download APC-3.1.13.tgz (171,591 bytes)
.....................................done: 171,591 bytes
55 source files, building
WARNING: php_bin /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php appears to have a suffix /php5.4.10/bin/php, but config variable php_suffix does not match
running: phpize
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
Enable internal debugging in APC [no] : 
Enable per request file info about files used from the APC cache [no] : 
Enable spin locks (EXPERIMENTAL) [no] : 
Enable memory protection (EXPERIMENTAL) [no] : 
Enable pthread mutexes (default) [no] : 
Enable pthread read/write locks (EXPERIMENTAL) [yes] : 
building in /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-benatespinagk8kAT/APC-3.1.13
running: /private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/configure --enable-apc-debug=no --enable-apc-filehits=no --enable-apc-spinlocks=no --enable-apc-memprotect=no --enable-apc-pthreadmutex=no --enable-apc-pthreadrwlocks=yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /opt/local/bin/gsed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking for PHP prefix... /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10
checking for PHP includes... -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/main -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/ext -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable APC support... yes, shared
checking whether we should enable cache request file info... no
checking whether we should use mmap... yes
checking whether we should use semaphore locking instead of fcntl... no
checking whether we should use pthread mutex locking... no
checking whether we should use pthread read/write locking... yes
pthread rwlocks are supported!
checking whether the target compiler supports builtin atomics... yes
checking whether we should use spin locks... no
checking whether we should enable memory protection... no
checking for zend_set_lookup_function_hook... no
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for union semun... yes
checking whether we should enable valgrind support... checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
yes
checking valgrind/memcheck.h usability... no
checking valgrind/memcheck.h presence... no
checking for valgrind/memcheck.h... no
checking for shm_open in -lrt... no
checking whether to include code coverage symbols... no
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if cc PIC flag -fno-common works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin12.4.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-benatespinagk8kAT/APC-3.1.13/libtool --mode=compile cc -D_GNU_SOURCE -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-benatespinagk8kAT/APC-3.1.13/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-benatespinagk8kAT/APC-3.1.13/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/main -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/ext -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c -o apc.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -D_GNU_SOURCE -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-benatespinagk8kAT/APC-3.1.13/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-benatespinagk8kAT/APC-3.1.13/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/main -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/ext -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/apc.o
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:34:
/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:61:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [apc.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```